# Terminal window always 80x2, can't resize

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04, and whenever I open a (GNOME) terminal window and try to resize, it always shrinks to 80x2. The same happens when I use the menu bar to choose dimensions.

Other program windows are not affected. And this behavior only happens when I use the "Ubuntu" session, and not the "Gnome (Default)" session.

Comment: Is it 80x2 or 80x24? I have the same problem, except the window stays 80x24, even if I select a different size from the _Advanced_ menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have changed the theme, it could be the reason. See the following bug report:
 [Gnome-terminal in Ubuntu Unity shrinks to minimum size](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1451944)

If you are using the ambient theme (default), it would be good if you could update the bug report.

I had the same issue with zukimac theme, but not with ambient or arc.

To fix this, try opening the Appearance application (e.g. from System Settings) and change the Theme to "Ambiance".

Comment: My default theme was "Adwaita", but changing it to "Ambiance" fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I confirm that this fix worked as written with 15.10 as well. (Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Try, right click on terminal. Go to `Profiles` -> `Profile Preferencis` then left click. You will got new window.

On `General` tab you have option `Use custom default terminal size`. Check option and change size of terminal. Go to close.

Close terminal. Open terminal. New opened terminal will be in size your specified.

Comment: Unfortunately the default profile's initial terminal window size is set to 80x24, but that is not the case and changing it does not fix the behavior of auto resizing to 80x2 whenever I try to stretch the window.